# Вывод формата 'H:M:S' на графике с использованием Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript

Возникла проблема отображения "продолжительности" на графике.

Не могу корректно перевести данные полученные с помощью php (количество секунд) в формат даты **"H:M:S"** на всплывающей подсказке.

Строка с данными (`$BaselineList`) по `x` - не столь важна.

Строка с данными (`$ValueList`) по `у`: 342000, 253000, 462000, 244000, 253000, 468000, 418000, 456000.

**Полученный график:**

[image: img]

**Код графика:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var chart;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: '<?php echo $name;?>',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: '<?php echo $name; ?>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                    categories: [<?php echo $BaselineList; ?>],
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -80,
                        y : 10,
                        align: 'right',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '<?php echo $name;?>'
                },              
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', new Date(this.value));
                    }
                },
                type: 'datetime',

            },
            legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -100,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                crosshairs: true,
                shared: true,

            },
            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 4,
                        lineColor: '#666666',
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name:'<?php echo $name ; ?>',
                color: '#191970',
                Axis: 1,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'square'
                },
                data: [<?php echo $ValueList; ?>]

            }]
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: А значит та хренотень по оси Х с полным раскладом вплоть до "Зима" вас вполне устраивает?))) Я лично, уже неделю бьюсь с корректным отображением Х оси, но самое корректное пока получилось типа 1, 2, 3, 4, но для этого нужно просто ничего не делать))))

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, сработает tooltip / dateTimeLabelFormats (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter), аналогично оси y.

А если нет - пишут, что можно просто задать весь выводимый текст:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return 'Duration: <b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', new Date(this.value));
 + '</b>';
  }
},
```